# relative percentage positioning on safari ios unexpected result

Tags: css, css-float

I am having a problem with safari on iOS where relatively positioned objects are not correctly observing their containers' box when the container's height is determined by floated content.

I have two spans contained in 2 anchors, which are floated one left and one right.
They have a fixed height and I want them vertically centered so I'm using `top:50%; margin-top:-25px` (half their height)

I think the issue is because there is no fixed height on the top container `div.drawer` it's set once the content of .labels > ul is cleared (the li's are floating left)

The important lines in the css are the top containers height line#7 (currently auto)
and the positioning of the spans on line#51 - 52

If I give `div.drawer` a fixed height (comment in #7) it all works as you'd expect;
however I would have expected auto height to work when floated content is cleared, it does in *all browsers* I've tested *except safari on iOS*.

**Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/robaldred/ANXsK/

[image: OK on Chrome Android]
[image: Fine on Safari Mac]
[image: iOS safari issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use position: absolute, left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0; to create a 100% height and width element.  I forked your fiddle with the added positioning.

```
.drawer .nav {
    position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/hYmpa/

I am not sure why under iOS height: 100% does not operate the same as it does on desktop.

Comment: nice! thanks a lot, works perfectly. I suspect the underlying cause is another mobile safari bug.